# How do you change approval for an edit.

Tags: support

I have just given approval for a wiki-edit, "lords-prayer", which I didn't intend to give. I didn't notice the tag. Can I remove my approval?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing to do retrospectively is just go in and edit the tag wiki yourself to fix whatever bit you don't actually think belongs.

**Edit:** The particular [suggested edit](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/17346) in question here has been rejected by other reviewers, so that's taken care of.

Comment: Thanks, Caleb. The edit isn't visible yet since it is waiting approval by others. I just thought if I could withdraw my approval, the process would be expedited. I even think, the person who proposed the edit must have thought he was writing an answer to a question. What he wrote doesn't make much sense as an explanation of the purpose of the tag.

Comment: @enegue In that event it will probably be rejected by other reviewers anyway. Don't sweat it.